# Running Angularjs example with Slim for REST Service

Tags: php, html, wamp, angularjs, slim

Im having problem making this example for an angularjs application using slim(PHP framework for RESTful Webservice) to run properly.  This is the link to the example
http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/02/sample-application-with-angular-js/

The angular part is working properly in terms of rendering and routing.  But the data seems to be not loading so I suspect that there must be something wrong with the webservice.  This is my first time to try an angular application with a webservice also my first time using the Slim framework.

This is the image of the angular app.

![AngularJS left list of wines did not load][1]

I hope you guys could point me to the right direction.
Im running on windows xp and using wampserver 2.2 and mysql for as my database

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem and it turns out that the issue does not concern **ANGULARJS** nor the **SLIM FRAMEWORK** the problem is with the **apache server** settings and with .htaccess file inside the angular-cellar/api folder

I checked the apache error logs and found this error

```
.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://localhost/angular-cellar/
```

[To solve](http://de77.com/other/apache-error-htaccess-invalid-command-rewriteengine-perhaps-misspelled-or-defined-by-a-module-not-included-in-the-server-configuration/comment-page-1#comment-216960) this I edited my httpd.conf file and uncommented

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

It turns out that Wampserver 2.2 has module mod_rewrite disabled by default. Thanks